# Dynamically Replace a URL with JS and Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Im tying to replace a Java script include using Greasemonkey, but I'm afraid it will break quickly because it is not dynamic. Here and example of my situation.

This is the include statement from the original site: 
`<script src="/asset/js/app.js?dc12383"></script>`

The ending `?dc12383` is what I assume to be some type of version number. 
I currently replace the js using the code:

```
function createScript(js, id) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    if (id) s.id = id;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    try { s.innerHTML = js; }
    catch(e) { s.innerText = js; }
    return s;
}

function replaceJs() {
     var js = {
        "asset/js/app.js?dc12383": ' *STUFF TO REPLACE*'
    };

    for (var i in js) {
        document.body.appendChild(createScript(js[i], i));
    }
}`
```

Any ideas on how to ignore that ending ?..... in the include?

Comment: I haven't looked at this or grease monkey in years, but with my experience now I would have queried, using ajax, the website... parsed it with a regex, then used that to decide what to replace.